# Is it possible to minify a project with Vue3, typescript in composition api and vitejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, minify

As the title states : Is it possible to minify a project with Vue3, typescript in composition api and vitejs ?

I have searched a lot and yet I cant find anything that really suits my needs and is compatible with the full stack.

It might not be possible but I ask this here as a last ressort, in addition that all related posts I found seem a bit old.

Comment: This is already done by default I believe. https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-minify

Comment: Yeah, It seems to do it a little but is really far from the minifying result I have seen for JS.